# something like virtual member(structure)

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have class A with basic members and functions:

```
class A{
public:
    typedef struct{
        int aa;
        int bb;
    } stEntry;
    stEntry entry;

    void function1();
    void function2();
};
```

Than class B that should extend class A including structure stEntry...

```
class B : public A{
public:
    typedef struct :stEntry
    {
        int cc;
    } stEntry;
    stEntry entry;

    void function3();
};
```

and then:

```
int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    a.entry.aa = 1;    
    b.entry.aa = 2;
    b.entry.cc = 3;

    cout << "class A:"<<sizeof(a)<< endl;
    cout << "class B:"<<sizeof(b)<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get

```
class A:8
class B:20
```

So class B contains 2 instances - 8 bytes(A class member) + 12 bytes(B class member).

Is there a way how to extend structure stEntry for class B? (without have 2 instances)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of, with virtual inheritance:

```
struct stEntryBase {
    int aa;
    int bb;
};

struct A : virtual stEntryBase {
    typedef stEntryBase stEntry;

    void function1();
    void function2();
};

struct stEntryDerived : virtual stEntryBase {
    int cc;
};

struct B : A, stEntryDerived {
    typedef stEntryDerived stEntry;

    void function3();
};
```

If you want to go another level of inheritance then `B` would derived virtually from `stEntryDerived`.

Now you have to refer to the fields as `a.aa`, `b.cc`, there is no member `entry`. Also, the `stEntry` types are no longer POD (so `bb` and `cc` may no longer be adjacent in memory). Finally, the size increase due to the virtual inheritance might actually be bigger than two `int`s.

What you can do, is get an `stEntryDerived*` or `stEntryDerived&` from an instance of `B`. Then that pointer/reference can be used to access `aa`, `bb`, and `cc` as the members of `stEntryDerived`, without the user needing to know about `B`. So you've achieved separation of interface, at some cost.

Comment: Thats great idea! Nevertheless I think lines "typedef stEntryBase stEntry;" and "typedef stEntryDerived stEntry;" are redundant.

Comment: @Meloun: sure, I left them just in case there's calling code that uses the type `B::stEntry` for anything.

Answer (score 4):

No, because **you're creating two instances yourself**. The base class has an instance, and the derived class has an instance (of a class extending the base class' inner class).

You can't modify the structure of the base class outside of it - once you defined it, it stays like that.